# How to iterate through mesh vertices and add hooks using script

Tags: python, mesh, scripting

do you know how I can iterate through all the vertices of a mesh, and add a new Empty object as a hook to them via using a script? Like you would do by clicking on them in Edit Mode and then pressing Ctrl+H.

I'm trying to achieve this by the following code unsuccessfully so far:

```
# I import the bpy and do various things here which work, but the below one doesn't

current_obj = bpy.context.object

for vert in current_obj.data.vertices:          
    vert.hook_add_newob()
```

Thank you for the support in advance!

Comment: bpy.ops.object.hook_add_newob()

Comment: Yes I tried this already and it also doesn't work. I can't even read the error message just that "Phython script fail, look in the console" - but there is nothing in the console...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import bpy, bmesh

# Create a persistent reference to current object
current_obj = bpy.data.objects[ bpy.context.object.name ]

bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode = 'EDIT' ) # Go to edit mode

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh( current_obj.data )

for i in range( len( bm.verts ) ):
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = current_obj
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all( action = 'DESELECT' ) # Deselect all vertices
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh( current_obj.data )
    bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
    v  = bm.verts[i]
    v.select = True
    bm.select_flush( True )
    bpy.ops.object.hook_add_newob()

bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode = 'OBJECT' )     # Back to object mode
```

Answer (score 2):

**It is now possible without edit mode nor operators.**

Can add a modifier assign it vertices and an object without requiring to be in edit mode, or running any operators.

*Have lazily added the empty with add empty operator below, but could be replaced with existing objects or `bpy.data.objects.new(name, None)` and linking to a collection linked to scene.  (Adding an object without operators  has been well covered on BSE)*

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
tri = context.object
if tri and tri.type == 'MESH':
    me = tri.data
    for v in me.vertices:
        name = f"Vert_{v.index}"
        bpy.ops.object.empty_add(
                location=tri.matrix_world @ v.co
                )
        mt = context.object
        mt.name = name
        hm = tri.modifiers.new(
                name=name,
                type='HOOK',
                )
        hm.object = mt
        hm.vertex_indices_set([v.index])
```

Used in answer here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/197166/15543